# WSO2 Dataservice large insert bug

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

When I use a large insert statement with around 100 columns, at the moment of the insertion columns are swapped.

I have checked ordinals, names but there's nothing I can do to make it work.

Have you had the issue before?

I am using Carbon 4.0.1 and installed ESB and AS features.

Comment: If you share any exceptions you can observer. That would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in the dataservices components released with Carbon 4.0.0 and 4.0.1. Basically, when you use a large number of columns, the ordinals of them appear to be getting shuffled deviating from the original(natural) order. This will be fixed in the next immediate release.

Regards,
Prabath

Comment: Thanks Prabath for your quick answer, are there any workaround in the meantime?

Comment: Prabath, do you know if this issue is corrected in 4.0.2? Thanks

Comment: You can give it a try with "named parameters" features which is available in DSS as an alternative. But I couldn't really try that out myself and test whether it works for the given scenario. Basically you can avoid specifying the ordinals for the input mappings of the query and use named parameters instead. A sample query with named parameters would look like "SELECT name FROM person WHERE id=:id" where "id" is an input mappings defined in your data service query configuration.